# How to add one point as a feature in an encoder-decoder time series model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm

I have been performing a seq2seq time-series prediction using encoder-decoder LSTM architecture. The input data to the model has 2 features, which are essentially two arrays: one is a dependent variable (y-values) and the other, an independent variable (x-values). The shape of the array is:

```
input_shape: (57, 20, 2)
```

Where, for example, the x and y-values of one time series are of the shape (1, 20, 2), and their positions in the 3D array being:

```
x = input_shape[:][:, 0]
y = input_shape[:][:, 1]
```

I am now faced with a challenge of feeding a point (an x-y timestep, so to speak) as an additional feature. Is there any way to do so?

**EDIT: I have added the model that I'm using based on the requests in the comments. It may be noted that the input size I mentioned is small here for reasons of simplicity. The actual input I am using is quite large.**

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0, input_shape = (input_shape.shape[1], 2)))

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, dropout=0, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh')))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, dropout=0, return_sequences=False)))

model.add((RepeatVector(targets.shape[1])))

model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, dropout=0, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh')))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, dropout=0, return_sequences=True)))

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(64, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='linear')))
model.build()
model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.Adam(0.00001), loss = 'MAE')
```

Comment: Is your point another feature or a time-lagged y-value? Are you trying to feed it to your encoder or into your decoder as another set of inputs along with your encoder layer's states?

Comment: The point is supposed to be a special point among the y-values, whose index would be the corresponding x-value. This point is an input (just like the other 2 features) to the encoder, and the encoder's outputs are fed to the decoder.

Comment: I may be wrong but it sounds like you're looking to implement something akin to an attention mechanism, where there is a special timestep in your input you want your network to focus on. Perhaps this will help? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344508/what-are-attention-mechanisms-exactly. If you're adamant with your current approach lmk I might be able to help out

Comment: Also I'm a tad bit confused about what the shape of your desired input is. You currently have both y and x in each timestep giving the shape (57,20,2), therefore shouldn't one batch be (1,20,2) not (1,20,1)? Are you trying to add the y,x vals of a special timestep in the past 20 into all your other timesteps within that 20 time steps, to make a (57,20,4) input?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry. My mistake. Yes, each batch should be of the shape (1, 20, 2) and I wish to add that special x-y timestep to make a net input of (57, 20, 4). I made the edit in my post :). Also, I have been using attention mechanisms, and that might not solve the problem. I am essentially having issues to represent a point as an additional feature, where the other (already existing) features are arrays.

Comment: I see. Would you mind also including your current auto-encoder architecture into your post, Imma take a gander

Comment: Is your problem more on you don't know how to feed the input into your architecture or more on the preprocessing side?

Comment: I added the model architecture I'm using. But I'm having problems on the former (I don't know HOW to feed the additional x-y point to the input, since the existing inputs are time series and the additional input is just supposed to be a point, one in every batch.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give your model two inputs, where the first input is your normal time series in the shape of (batch,20,2) and a second input of your special time point in the shape (batch,2). Then define the following architecture that repeats your special point 20 times to get (batch,20,2) which is then concatenated with your normal input. (Note i defined `target_shape_1` to make sure it compiles on my end, but you can replace it with `target.shape[1]`)

```
input_shape_1 = 20
target_shape_1 = 3

normal_input = Input(shape=(20, 2), name='normal_inputs') #your normal time series (None,20,2) (Batch,time,feats)

key_time_point = Input(shape=(2),name='key_time_point') #your single special point (None,2) (Batch,feats)

key_time_repeater = RepeatVector(20,name='key_time_repeater') #repeat your special point 20 times 
key_time_repeater_out = key_time_repeater(key_time_point) #turning your (None,2) into (None,20,2)


initial_mask = Masking(mask_value=0, input_shape = (20, 4))

masked_out = initial_mask( 
    #concat your normal input (None,20,2) and repeated input (None,20,2) 
    #into (None, 20,4) and feed to nn
    tf.concat([normal_input,key_time_repeater_out],len(normal_input.shape)-1) 
)

encoder_1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, dropout=0, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh'))
encoder_2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, dropout=0, return_sequences=False))
encoder_repeat = RepeatVector(target_shape_1)
encoder_out = encoder_repeat(encoder_2(encoder_1(masked_out)))

decoder_1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, dropout=0, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh'))
decoder_2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, dropout=0, return_sequences=True))
decoder_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
decoder_out = decoder_dense(decoder_2(decoder_1(encoder_out)))

final_output = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='linear'))(decoder_out)

model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=[normal_input, key_time_point], outputs=final_output)
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.00001), loss = 'MAE')
```

A `summary()` of the model looks like this:

```
Model: "model_1"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
key_time_point (InputLayer)     [(None, 2)]          0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
normal_inputs (InputLayer)      [(None, 20, 2)]      0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
key_time_repeater (RepeatVector (None, 20, 2)        0           key_time_point[0][0]             
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_concat_3 (TensorFlo [(None, 20, 4)]      0           normal_inputs[0][0]              
                                                                 key_time_repeater[0][0]          
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
masking_4 (Masking)             (None, 20, 4)        0           tf_op_layer_concat_3[0][0]       
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_12 (Bidirectional (None, 20, 256)      136192      masking_4[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_13 (Bidirectional (None, 256)          394240      bidirectional_12[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
repeat_vector_11 (RepeatVector) (None, 3, 256)       0           bidirectional_13[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_14 (Bidirectional (None, 3, 256)       394240      repeat_vector_11[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
bidirectional_15 (Bidirectional (None, 3, 256)       394240      bidirectional_14[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_7 (TimeDistrib (None, 3, 64)        16448       bidirectional_15[0][0]           
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
time_distributed_8 (TimeDistrib (None, 3, 1)         65          time_distributed_7[0][0]         
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,335,425
Trainable params: 1,335,425
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: I didn't have any data to feed it to fully test it out but I think it'll fit. lmk if you got any problems

Comment: This looks like a way! I'll try it out and update the result findings here!

Comment: My simulation is running atm. Irrespective of whether it predicts correctly or not, you did help with the specific query of data representation, and very generously to say the least. Thanks a lot, @Jeff :)

Comment: @HarryS always happy to help :]